# SCSS @import statements inside Rails Engine results in error: `Aborted (core dumped)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rails-engines

I am having trouble using SCSS `@import` statements within any of my Rails Engines. Can someone please help me sort this out? Here are some details:

- Using `@import` within any SCSS files within the Rails engine files causes the main application to crash. Here are the last two lines that the logger shows.

  - `Rendered <snipped> (Duration: 87.4ms | Allocations: 33352)`
  - `Aborted (core dumped)`
- SCSS works correctly within the engine when `@import` is not used
- SCSS `@import` statements work correctly within my main applications asset files
- I am running Rails 6.0 and `sassc-rails`

So far I cannot find any way to get them working. Can someone please help me sort this out?

Comment: have same error but I were not able to recognize the root cause, Unfortunately no luck to get it down yet

Comment: are you loading static assets, if so, can you please share the code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually was a bug with `thin` server which I have been using in development, switching to `puma` solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with one of our scss files that was still using @import "foo.css" syntax.  Changing syntax to @import url(foo.css) fixed it for us.

Not clear what syntax you are using from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `}` missing in scss file and got the same error.

Adding missing `}` fixed the error in my case.

Please check your latest changes in scss/css files once.